# Estimating right-censored data

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, censoring

I am VERY new to stats.  I have a large amount of life-time data (delay in arrival since start of experiment) from repeat experiments.  Some data is missing, but essentially represents a delay longer than the experiment time (right-censored data).

I want to estimate this data.  I could use the experiment time for each missing data, but I understand this is not useful above a certain data size. I understand there are statistical strategies to estimate using the distribution of the non-missing values, the fact that the missing data is right-censored and some kind of maximum likelihood equation to find the parameters (missing data) that would have the highest probability of giving the non-missing data, given the distribution.

However, this is not the larger part of my work, and I am really looking to use some kind of tool, rather than endless manual crunching.  Or...   If there were available a very clear pseudo code algorithm, I could easily port it to C/C++, because the original data is generated in my C++ application.  The data is later offloaded into Excel and so alternatively achieving the same thing in Excel that would be nearly as useful, but not quite.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.