# Estimate of censored poisson process

Tags: estimation, matlab, poisson-distribution, censoring, poisson-process

I have a set of processes, each of which has number of events and the total length of time. I'm trying to model them as independent Poisson processes with there own rates. The rate of the ith process may be estimate thus

$$
\lambda_{i} = \frac{n_{i}}{T}
$$

however many of the processes do not generate any events and so have a $\lambda$ of zero

We can use the estimates of lambda to generate simulated processes, with the goal of comparing the empirical recruitment curve (when the first event was emitted for each $i$) to simulated ones under the model.

From [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77545/simulating-poisson-processes). Draw  $X_{i} \sim Pois(\lambda_{i}T ) $ and use to generate $X_{i}$ uniform random numbers on $(0\space T)$. Take the smallest value to be the recruitment for each $i$.

This seems to give a biased estimate, since *some* processes with a non-zero observed rate are simulated with a zero rate, but *no* processes with a zero-observed rate are simulated with a non-zero rate.

It seems like this is a similar question to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56478/estimating-right-censored-data) one.
Although, unlike lifetime data, in this case some of the processes may truly have a zero rate.

EDIT
I'm adding a simulation in matlab that seems to suggest that simulating the recruitment as $n_{i}$ uniformly distributed events rather than $Pois(n_{i})$ uniformly distributed events is the correct thing to do

```
N = 500;
L = nbinrnd(0.5,0.2,N,1);    %real distribution of lambdas (could be any distribution though)
nEvt = poissrnd(L);          %actual number of events   
rEvt = [];                   %actual recruitment 

for i = 1:numel(nEvt)
    if nEvt(i)>0
        rEvt(i) = min(rand(nEvt(i),1));   %simulate the true recruitment
    else
        rEvt(i) = inf;
    end
end

nS = 2000;                         %shuffles
xsim = nan(N+1,nS);                %save the xpostion of the ecdf
xsim2 = nan(N+1,nS);               %save the xpostion of the ecdf
for s = 1:nS
    nEvtSim = poissrnd(nEvt);         %number of events simulated as a poisson draw
    nEvtSim2 = (nEvt);                %number of events simulated SAME as number of actual events
    rEvtSim = nan(numel(nEvtSim),1);  
    rEvtSim2 = nan(numel(nEvtSim),1);  

    for i = 1:numel(nEvtSim)
        if nEvtSim(i)>0
            rEvtSim(i) = min(rand(nEvtSim(i),1));
        else
            rEvtSim(i) = inf;       %never had an event
        end

        if nEvtSim2(i)>0
            rEvtSim2(i) = min(rand(nEvtSim2(i),1));
        else
            rEvtSim2(i) = inf;       %never had an event
        end 
    end

    [f,xsim(:,s)]= ecdf(rEvtSim);   %work out the ecdf
    [f,xsim2(:,s)]= ecdf(rEvtSim2);   %work out the ecdf
end
xsim = sort(xsim,2);
h1 = stairs(xsim(:,nS*[0.025 0.975]),[f f],'color',[0.9 0.9 0.9]); %95% confidence interval
hold on

xsim2 = sort(xsim2,2);
h2 = stairs(xsim2(:,nS*[0.025 0.975]),[f f],'color',[1 0.9 0.9]); %95% confidence interval

[f,x]= ecdf(rEvt);
h3 = stairs(x,f,'color','k');  %real data recruitment
hold off

legend([h3 h1(1) h2(2)],{'actual data','poiss(N) events','N events'})
```